# Server frequently loses Azure SignalR connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

My ASP.NET Web API (target framework: .NET Framework 4.6.2) project frequently loses connection with Azure SignalR service (**free tier**). I have followed the example as shown in **aspnet** ‘chatroom’ [example](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/blob/master/aspnet-samples/ChatRoom/Startup.cs).

My client application is based on Angular JS. Messages are being send to the clients but after a few hours, the server connection with Azure SignalR service is lost and is not established again.

As far as I understand from the MS Azure SignalR Internals [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-internals):

> If a server connection is disconnected for network issue,
>
> - the server connection starts reconnecting **automatically**.

The following error is returned back in response:

> Azure SignalR Service is not connected yet, please try again later

However, this does not seem to be happening i.e. server connection with Azure SignalR service is not established again.

[image]

`nuget` packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR v2.4.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core v2.4.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb v2.4.0
- Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet v1.0.0-preview1-10317
- Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Protocols v1.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/404) with `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet v1.0.0-preview1-10317`. The fix is planned to be released this week.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added error handling code in your client like below-

```js
 // Define handlers for any errors
        //
        this.hubConnection.error((error: any) => {
            // Push the error on our subject
            //
            this.hubConnection.start()
                .done(() => {
                    this.startingSubject.next();

                    //Invoke connect method on Hub
                    //  this.hubProxy.invoke("Connect", userId, usertype);

                })
                .fail((error: any) => {
                    this.startingSubject.error(error);
                });
        });
```

Also in case of closed connection code would be like

```js
this.hubConnection.onclose(() => { 
    setTimeout(function(){
    this.hubConnection.start()
               .done(() => {
                    this.startingSubject.next();

                        //Invoke connect method on Hub
                      //  this.hubProxy.invoke("Connect", userId, usertype);

                   })
                  .fail((error: any) => {
                        this.startingSubject.error(error);
                   });
       },3000); 
   });
```

Hope it helps.

**MV**

Comment: Server’s connection to Azure SignalR service is lost. This code is for reconnecting client.